# Popcorn.js : Create a sequence of Vimeo videos

Tags: jquery, html, vimeo, popcornjs

I'd like to use the popcorn.js API to create a sequence of multiple Vimeo files. As soon as a video ends, the next video as to load & play.

I have troubles figuring out how to do this. I wanted to use the "ended" event, but apparently, it doesn't work with Vimeo... So right now, I don't really know how to do, I'm not even sure I should use the popcorn.js API, that I chose only because of its footnote feature.

Can someone here help me?

Thanks a lot in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the sequencer Popcorn.js Sequencer module, which does basically what you are looking for:  http://popcornjs.org/popcorn-docs/modules/#data%20timeline%20sources

Best,
Eric

Comment: A quick look at that pages shows this to be an incorrect assumption. The sequence code requires an array of src, Start, End. Popcorn creates player objects to deal with Vimeo urls. There appears to be no cross over of the two features.